# hooking up a humidifier on a carrier infinity furnace

Tags: furnace, humidifier

Hello I would like to hook up my desert spring rotary disc humidifier to my new carrier infinity model #59MN7 furnace. I see the control board in the furnace has a HUM (humidifier) terminal and a 24VAC screw terminal. Is it really that simply or am I missing something? I have the carrier infinity touch control thermostat hooked up to it. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for your unit.

> The HUM terminal is a 24 VAC output, energized when the blower is operating during a call for heat.
>
> Connect an accessory 24 VAC, 0.5 amp. maximum humidifier (if used) to the ¼ in. male quick-connect HUM terminal and COM-24V screw terminal on the control board thermostat strip.
>
> **NOTE:** If the humidifier has its own 24 VAC power supply, an isolation relay may be required. Connect the 24 VAC coil of the isolation relay to the HUM and COM/24V screw terminal on the control board thermostat strip. (See Fig. 32.)
>
> [image: Figure 32.]

So if the humidifier is less than 0.5 amperes, then you can simply use the HUM and COM terminals.  Otherwise you'll need an alternate power supply, and an isolation relay.